# Solve the Diophantine equation $x^6 + 3x^3 + 1 = y^4$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math, diophantine-equations, quadratics

> Find all pairs $(x, y)$ of integers, such that $x^6 + 3x^3 + 1 = y^4$.

My solution:

Claim: The pair $(0, 1)$ are the only solutions.

Proof. Suppose there exists other solutions for $y \gt 1$ and $x \gt 0$, then I shall show that such pairs are impossible if $x$ and $y$ are integers. Let us Factorize the given equation as follows.

$x^6 + 3x^3 = y^4 - 1$

$x^6 + 3x^3  = (y^2)^2  - 1^2$

$x^6 + 3x^3 =(y^2 - 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + 1)$

$x^3(x^3+ 3) = (y - 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + 1) . . . (*)$

Because  the numbers $(y - 1), (y + 1)$, and $(y^2 + 1)$ are all distinct, it follows that their products can never be a cube, hence, from $(*)$, we obtain the system.

$(y - 1)(y + 1)(y^2 + 1) = x^3 + 3$, and
$x^3 = 1$,
Which is equivalent to:

$(y - 1)(y + 1)(y^2 +) = 4 . . .(**)$

Since $(y - 1) \gt 0$, then $y$ is minimum if and only if $y = 2$ which clearly does not satisfy $(**)$. Hence we must have $x = 0$ and $y = 1$.

Please, Is there any mistake in my solution?.

Comment: Knowing that three numbers are distinct does not imply that their product is not a cube ($1\times 8 \times 27$ is a cube).  More seriously, even if we agree that this particular product is not a cube, that wouldn't mean that it isn't divisible by a cube so how would you then conclude that $x^3=1$?

Comment: You mean $(0,\pm 1)$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$x^6+3x^3+1-y^4=0$ is a quadratic equation.

Thus, there is an integer $n$ for which $$3^2-4(1-y^4)=n^2$$ or
$$n^2-4y^4=5$$ or
$$(n-2y^2)(n+2y^2)=5$$
and we have four cases only.

Comment: Why do you call $x^6+3x^3+1-y^4=0$ a "quadratic" equation?

Comment: It's quadratic in $x^3$.

Answer (score 7):

**Case 1.** If $x= 0$ we have $y^4=1$ thus $y=\pm 1$

**Case 2.** If $x>0$ then

$(x^3+1)^2= x^6+2x^3+1<  x^6 + 3x^3 + 1 = y^4$

$ y^4 = x^6 + 3x^3 + 1< x^6+4x^3+4 = (x^3+2)^2$

So we have:$$(x^3+1)^2< y^4 <(x^3+2)^2$$

So $x^3+1< y^2 < x^3+2$ a contradiction.

**Case 3.** If $x<0$ then write $x=-t$ and $t>0$. Now we have to sove:

$$t^6 - 3t^3 + 1 = y^4$$ and this can be done in similar fashion:

$$(t^3-2)^2<y^4<(t^3-1)^2$$

Comment: $x^6+2x^3+1<x^6+3x^3+1$ iff $0<x^3$ iff $0<x$. OP said "integers", which includes negative integers.

Comment: Here OP means "original poster". By the way, you could've googled "OP meaning/definition".

Comment: $\left(t^3-2\right)^2<t^6-3t^3+1$ is equivalent to $3<t^3$. You have to check the case $t=1$. $x=-1$ doesn't give a solution.